# How do I set a different type of property in mongoose schema from the defined type?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose-schema

I have a Mongoose schema set up for a user profile on a forum. What I'd like to do is set up the user's forum title to be an `ObjectID` and reference the Title schema. I already have this part set up. However by default I'd like for this field to be a string called "Noob" until a title is set from the user's profile which then would change this value to an `ObjectID` referencing the Title from the database.

```
title: {
  type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: 'Title',
  default: 'Noob'
},
```

This is what I have and is basically what I'm wanting to achieve, however this throws an error because the default I set is a string and not an `ObjectID`. I'm not sure how to achieve this or what alternatives I may have.

Comment: Why not make the type `string`, and convert `ObjectId` to `string` once the title is set?

Comment: @brandonscript so have it start as a string. Then when the user sets it for the first time change to ObjectID? Am I still able to leave the "ref: 'Title'" doing it this way?

Comment: No I mean on the fly, convert ObjectId to string `this.objectid.toString()`

Comment: Hm. Wouldn't this defeat the purpose of using ObjectID as the reference? I was using ObjectID as the datatype so that it uses up less memory when storing it in the database. The application is expected to be very large, with 100s of thousands of accounts, so even the smallest change in memory storage size is somewhat of a big deal. The default string would only be a temporary measure until it's changed by the user, at which point I was hoping to convert to an ObjectID

Comment: Sure, but then you aren't going to be able to use "noob" - a string - to be its default. What about using an ObjectId of all 0s?

Comment: That may work. I could use something in my application to check if the ObjectID is all 0's first and if it is then return the string Noob, and if not then do the database lookup for the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've pointed out that you want to maintain the strong type `ObjectId` for performance reasons, you'll have to use that same type as the default. You could use an id of all 0s for example:

```
title: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Title",
    default: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
}
```

You can then check for this and display "Noob" in its place later?

Comment: This seems like the best answer for my use case. I didn't think of this at first, but it could definitely work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can just make it a string:

```
title: {
  type: String,
  ref: 'Title',
  default: 'Noob'
},
```

You can still set it as an `ObjectID`-looking string later.

You can't have it both ways: if you want a field to be an `ObjectID` type, then it needs to hold `ObjectID`s. If you want to be able to hold strings in it, then it needs to be of type `String`.

If `title` is a reference to an `ObjectID` in another collection, Mongoose will still cast an `ObjectID`-ish string to an `ObjectID` when it performs the lookup:

`Title.find({ _id: doc.title })` will still lookup an `ObjectID` if the `doc.title` is a string.